# Silverstripe group result by specific subject

Tags: group-by, silverstripe

I have Theses(datamodel) and Subject(datamodel) and Author(datamodel) i want to display my results grouped by subject

e.g.

- Subject1
  -Theses1
  -Theses2
- Subject2
  -Theses3

...

what i have so far is the following

```
<?php
class ThesisDissertations extends Page {
}
class ThesisDissertations_Controller extends Page_Controller {
public function getSubject() {
    $subjectgroup = new PaginatedList(Subject::get());
    return $subjectgroup;
    }


public function ThesesDissertations() {
    $pages = new PaginatedList(Theses::get()
        ->leftJoin("Author", "Theses.AuthorID = Author.ID")
        ->leftJoin("Subject", "Theses.SubjectID = Subject.ID")
        ->where("Theses.SubjectID = 'getSubject'")
        ->sort('SubjectTitle'), $this->getRequest());
    $pages->setPageLength(15);
    return $pages;
    }
}
```

and for the template

```
<div class="container"><ul><% loop $getSubject %>
$SubjectTitle
<br>
<% loop $ThesesDissertations %>
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<li><a href="" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#$ID"><strong>$Author.AuthorName</strong></a></li>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="$ID" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>$TitleTH</strong></h4>
    <em>$CallNo, $Author.AuthorName </em>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p class="text-justify">$Summary<br>Subjects : <em>$Subject.SubjectTitle</em>
    <hr>
    <em><strong>Physical Description :</strong> <% if $PhysicalDesc="" %>No Description Available<% else %>$PhysicalDesc<% end_if %><br>
    <strong>Degree Course :</strong> $DegreeCourse<br>
    <strong>Year Published :</strong> $Year</em></p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div><br><% end_loop %><% end_loop %></ul></div>
```

Subject DataObject

```
class Subject extends DataObject{

private static $db = array (
 'SubjectTitle' => 'Varchar',
    );

    private static $has_many = array (
     'Theses' => 'Theses',
    );

public function canView($member = null) {
    return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
}

public function canEdit($member = null) {
    return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
}

public function canDelete($member = null) {
    return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
}

public function canCreate($member = null) {
    return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
}

private static $summary_fields = array(
    'SubjectTitle',
);
}
?>
```

Theses Dataobject

class Theses extends DataObject{

```
private static $db = array (
     'CallNo' => 'Varchar',
 'AuthorID' => 'Int',
 'TitleTH' => 'Text',
 'Year' => 'Int(4)',
 'PhysicalDesc' => 'Text',
 'Notes' => 'Text',
 'Summary' => 'Text',
 'SubjectID' => 'Int',
 'DegreeCourse' => 'Varchar',
    );

    private static $has_one = array (
    'Author' => 'Author',
    'Subject' => 'Subject',
    );

    private static $field_labels = array(
    'CallNo' => 'Call Number',
    'TitleTH' => 'Title Headings',
    'Author.AuthorName'=>'Author',
    'DegreeCourse'=>'Degree Course',
    'Year'=>'Year Published',
    'Subject.SubjectTitle'=>'Subject',
);

    private static $summary_fields = array (
    'CallNo' => 'CallNo',
    'TitleTH' => 'TitleTH',
    'Author.AuthorName',
    'DegreeCourse',
    'Year'=>'Year',
    'Subject.SubjectTitle',
    );

    public function getCMSfields() {
     $fields = FieldList::create(TabSet::create('Root'));
     $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', array(
        TextField::create('CallNo'),
        DropdownField::create('AuthorID','AuthorName')->setEmptyString('-Select one-')->setSource(Author::get()->sort('AuthorName')->map('ID','AuthorName')),
        TextField::create('TitleTH'),
        NumericField::create('Year','Year')->setMaxLength(4),
        TextField::create('PhysicalDesc'),
        TextField::create('Notes'),
        TextAreaField::create('Summary'),
        DropdownField::create('DegreeCourse','DegreeCourse',array('BLIS' => 'BLIS','BLS' => 'BLS','MLIS' => 'MLIS','MLS' => 'MLS')),
        DropdownField::create('SubjectID','SubjectTitle')->setEmptyString('-Select one-')->setSource(Subject::get()->sort('SubjectTitle')->map('ID','SubjectTitle')),
    ));

    return $fields;
    }
}
?>
```

Author dataobject[if you ever wanted]

```
class Author extends DataObject{

private static $db = array (
 'AuthorName' => 'Varchar',
    );

    private static $has_many = array (
     'Theses' => 'Theses',
    );

public function canView($member = null) {
    return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
}

public function canEdit($member = null) {
    return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
}

public function canDelete($member = null) {
    return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
}

public function canCreate($member = null) {
    return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_MyAdmin', 'any', $member);
}

private static $summary_fields = array(
    'AuthorName',
); }?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you've got exactly. In your datamodels, I take it that every thesis has a subject, and every subject can have multiple theses, and that these relations are defined in your models. Then you can supply your template with a list of subjects. You don't have to use a controller function for that. So just add "Subjects" => Subject::get() to the array that you pass to the template, and you can do the following: (shortened and untested, but you'll get the drift):

```
<% loop $Subjects %>
    $SubjectTitle
    <% loop $Theses %>
        $CallNo, $Author.AuthorName
    <% endloop %>
<% endloop %>
```

When you want to have Subjects available to the template, you can do the following.

In the page controller (in your case ThesisDissertations_Controller), add the following function:

```
public function index() {
    return array("Subjects" => Subject::get());
}
```

You can pass all kinds of information to the template this way.

Comment: where should i put Subjects=> Subject::get()

Comment: i did what you've instructed... but it only displays the subjects and repeats itself as many as the number of theses in my database...

Comment: That's illogical. Could you show the code of the two dataobjects?

Comment: i edited my post.. adding the codes for my dataobjects

Comment: I don't see why my code shouldn't work, other than that I would call the theses class "thesis", keeping the naming consistent. Also, you specify some unnecessary fields in the getCMSfields function, as the CMS will scaffold the available fields in the $db mostly the same as you do it. Can you check if each subject has coupled the correct theses, that the CallNo and Author.AuthorName are filled and that you did not provide the $Theses variable to the template yourself?

Comment: sorry it is my fault though does this affect if i did not a declare a subject for the theses?

Comment: When you set a subject for a thesis (the has_one), it will automatically mean that the has_many on the subject dataobject is set as well. It does detect the theses. I see that your HTML is strange, though. You have an ul, with in it a li, but also extra divs and a br. Maybe move those inside the li ... Could be that's your problem?

Comment: Thanks problem solved.....now im moving to creating a searchbar that can search throughout the theses database..which will be another topic.. hope you can help me with it when i post it here..

Comment: So, what was the problem in the end?

Comment: some of my theses does not have a subject which is equal to '0' but there is no subject with '0' as id so it will not load the theses with no subjects..